# Can I repair a corrupted Ubuntu ISO file?

Tags: downloads

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 desktop LTS (701 MB). I tried it in Linux Live USB Creator. After adding this file, it shows that it is a corrupted file. But I didn't get any error while extracting it to the USB stick.

I got error while installing. It shows "Error 5 Input/Output". Please tell me how to fix the Corrupted file. I cannot download it again, because it took 3 days to download for my system.

Answer (score 2):

Can I necro-bump?

Actually, there is a way to repair corrupted ISOs

1. Grab a torrent of the required ISO
2. In your client specify the target to 'overwrite' the damaged ISO
3. The client will now 'Check' the ISO and re-download the corrupted bytes only
4. Done

Comment: Couldn't help but add a link to this AWESOME answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/239868/306707

Comment: We welcome great answers regardless of chronology.

Answer (score 1):

If the ISO is corrupted, then you'll have no choice but to redownload it, or order a CD from the Canonical store for it (you'll then need to pay for shipping and the CD).

There's no method to truly fixing a corrupted ISO.

Comment: So please tell me the link from where Ubuntu is available to free download. Previously i downloaded it form Ubuntu.com. So please tell me any other link

Comment: That link is still valid, you likely did not have a full ISO download (completely).  You could try the torrents though.

Comment: So kindly please tell me which version of Ubuntu has more features.

Comment: I mean which version of Ubuntu is better to download. Or is there any other linux OS is best when comparing to Ubuntu.?I am going to take your advice and then i will decide to download that one.

Comment: This *is* Ask ubuntu, you'll only ever hear Ubuntu derivatives from me.  Define "features" as each has their own features.  I personally like Ubuntu, but if you want slightly more pretty items, go Kubuntu (note you need a VERY GOOD system for that, as it can be memory intensive).

Comment: It can be repaired as a torrent - only corrupted pieces will be redownloaded.

Comment: @izx isnt that if it was only originally downloaded as a torrent?

Comment: @LordofTime not necessarily