# How to identify and replace broken files in a corrupted Ubuntu ISO?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, windows, iso, md5sum

So, this isn't exactly an issue running Ubuntu, but rather with installing it.

Every time I try to download the Ubuntu ISO (from any source) it seems to end up corrupt. That is, the MD5 sums are never correct.

The Ubuntu ISO files come with a file that lists all the files in the ISO, and their respective MD5SUMs.

What I wish to do is loop over this file, and compare them to their files in the ISO, and work out what files are corrupt, in the hopes that I can extract the corrupt files from one of the other iso files, to create a working installer.

But, I don't know how to do this, and of course, to make it worse, I have to do this from Windows 7.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't Jigdo (the Debian preferred way) be capable of doing this? It's main purpose now is to do delta updates for point releases on ISOs via updating packages within the ISOs. [about Debian ISOs and Jigdo](http://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/)

Comment: @gertvdijk Not for Ubuntu's desktop ISOs, because they mostly contain just a single file (see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/239868/22949)). That's why the desktop ISO's don't have associated `.jigdo` files on the download servers. The alternate CD and server CD ISO's *do* have `.jigdo` files. The desktop ISO's have the Ubiquity installer, which works by writing the live CD system to the disk and then making changes to it so it's prepared for normal (installed) use.

Comment: @EliahKagan That makes sense. Okay, in that case, shouldn't there be [PAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) parity block files to fix up complete ISOs? That's a lot more efficient, a lot easier, and more universal. *"Parchive was originally written to solve the problem of reliably transferring files on Usenet,[1] but it is now commonly used for protecting any kind of data from data corruption, bit rot, and accidental or malicious damage."*

Comment: Why would PAR be better than `zsync`? Even if PAR were supported officially by the Ubuntu project (like `zsync` is), are there notable advantages? About jigdo: It is applicable to the alternate and server CD's. They use `debian-installer`, creating a bare bones system, chrooting in and installing packages. So they have all the `.deb` files, located in the package pool (which contains just a tiny few files on desktop CD's). They can easily be assembled with `.jigdo` (or other methods). You may want to post a `jigdo`-based answer for server/alternate about how to download just the broken files.

Comment: @EliahKagan Should have mentioned that - PAR can do stuff *offline*, e.g. "you need 3 parity blocks to repair", feed them, "okay, fixing stuff... done!". Zsync effectively needs a complete good copy of it (remote in this case). But yeah, principle is the same. BTW, I see that Zsync can handle `gzip`ed archives very well, but that intelligence is useless on SquashFS, I assume? Anyway, for Ubuntu ISOs zsync is the way to go, indeed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Actually, I Know Which File Is Corrupted

Trying to combine files from multiple corrupted ISO images into a single, good ISO image is not a good approach to this problem. Here's why.

*Almost all* the data in the ISO image belongs to *just one* file, `casper/filesystem.squashfs`.

<sup>On an Ubuntu desktop CD or DVD ISO image, that is. On a server CD image or alternate CD image, it's a different story.</sup>

[image: Nautilus properties for filesystem.squashfs on an Ubuntu 12.10 i386 desktop CD]

So I can tell you right now what file is almost certainly corrupt on each of the ISO's you downloaded: that file, on all of them. When something is corrupted in an Ubuntu ISO, the bad bytes are almost always somewhere in there.

`filesystem.squashfs` is *itself* a disk image; it is mounted as part of booting the system on the live CD. You could potentially extract it from the ISO, then extract *its* contents, see what's corrupted, and replace the corrupted files. While you can mount or extract a squashfs filesystem on Windows, you'd likely find doing so to be a nontrivial task. And this image is compressed, so there's no guarantee that minor corruption in the containing ISO won't affect multiple files.

Furthermore, if you've tried download the ISO image *several times* and it's always corrupt, you can be pretty sure it's not just *minor* corruption. You might have to replace hundreds or thousands of files if you attempted to do it this way.

**Instead, you should download the ISO image using a more reliable method.**

Conveniently, one of them (`zsync`) is similar to what you're thinking, except that it will download just the necessary pieces of the ISO files, rather than just the necessary files contained within it.

## Make Sure You're Comparing Against the Right MD5 Hash

The first thing to do when your MD5 sum is wrong--*especially* if it's wrong after you download the file again--is to make sure you're comparing it against the MD5 hash for the correct file.

My guess is that

- you have an 12.04 LTS image and you're using an MD5 hash for a 12.04.1 LTS image
  (which is [not the same file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions)), *or*
- you have a 12.04.1 LTS image and you're using an MD5 hash for a 12.04 LTS image, *or*
- you have a 32-bit ("i386") image and you're using an MD5 hash for a 64-bit image, *or*
- you have a 64-bit ("amd64") image and you're using an MD5 hash for a 32-bit image.

[The list of MD5 hashes for each file is here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

In general, if your MD5 hash is wrong but the same for more than one download, usually

- you're comparing against the wrong hash, *or*
- the file is corrupted on the server (so if that looks to be the case, download from a different mirror, and, if you are willing, report a bug against ubuntu-website-content so the problem gets fixed), *or*
- you're using a proxy or VPN that caches web content, and it has somehow cached a corrupted copy (downloading from another mirror should fix that too), *or*
- you're downloading via FTP and a problem with the server or with your FTP client is causing the file to transfer in text mode rather than binary mode (this will corrupt it, and usually corrupt it the same way each time), *or*
- your connection is being deliberately intercepted and altered by a malicious third party who is deliberately feeding you the wrong file (this is usually quite unlikely, though).

You can manually select a (different) download mirror [at the bottom of this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

*If your ISO image really is corrupted, here are some ways to get a good file.*

## zsync

[`zsync`](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/) (see also [here](http://freecode.com/projects/zsync)) is a utility that can turn a *partially correct* file into a *totally correct* file by downloading just the parts you don't have the right versions of. Its primary application is for downloading slightly updated images, like those from one nightly build to another.

The way `zsync` works is this: Someone offering the file (like the Ubuntu project) creates a `.zsync` file which contains many checksums--checksums corresponding to many small parts of the file, rather than just one checksum for the whole file. You start out with anywhere from nothing to the entire file.

With nothing, the whole file is downloaded. With part of the file (that is, a file by the same name that's a different size or the same size with any number of binary differences), it figures out what parts need to be downloaded, and just downloads those parts. With the whole file, it doesn't download anything.

For *very unreliable Internet connections*, `zsync` is not much better than a web browser for downloading an entire file from scratch, *unless you're willing to run it two or more times, in which case, later runs will correct the problems in earlier runs*. For all but the highest error rate Internet connections, running zsync twice or, occasionally, three times on a file should be sufficient.

But you don't have to worry nearly as much about running `zsync` multiple times. Since you already--presumably--have most of the file, so that shouldn't be a problem. And as always if `zsync` gives you something corrupted, you can always run `zsync` again to fix it.

#### Getting `zsync` for Windows

`zsync` traditionally runs on Unix-like system (which doesn't really include Windows). However, recently [a native Windows port of `zsync` has been created](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/zsync-windows/new_dashboard), so you can probably use that.

`zsync` is a command-line program, so in Windows you run it in the Command Prompt. (One way to open the command-prompt is to type `cmd.exe` into the text box in the Start menu and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or, in Windows XP and earlier, Start > Run > `cmd.exe`.)

#### Another Way: Getting `zsync` for Cygwin

If you have any problems with the Windows port of `zsync`, you can always use the Cygwin version. Cygwin provides a Unix-like environment for Windows. It does not allow compiled executables to be run (for example, you could not use `zsync` from the Ubuntu package), but uses special versions of programs compiled for it from source. (It is far easier to compile a program written for Unix-like operating systems in Cygwin, than to compile it so it works natively on Windows.)

1. First, [get Cygwin's installer (`setup.exe`) from here](http://cygwin.com/) (or use [this direct link](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)).
2. Run it, click **Next** on the first screen, then select *Install from Internet* and click **Next** again.
3. On the next two screens, put Cygwin and the local package directory wherever you like them (defaults are usually good).
4. Select your Internet connection type (*Direct Connection* is usually good), and `setup.exe` will download a list of mirrors.
5. Pick any mirror, and it will download a list of available packages. You'll probably be warned about how this version is different from the previous one. That's not a problem, unless you've been using a previous version of Cygwin on the same machine.

   [image: Setup Alert message about how how this is the first time you've installed this particular version of Cygwin. If you haven't used Cygwin before, this can be ignored. As it says, "If this is the first time you've installed Cygwin on this system then you can ignore this message."]
6. Now you can select what packages to install. There is a text box for searching packages by name. Type `zsync` there (but *do not* press <kbd>Enter</kbd>--if you do, it's like clicking *Next*). An entry for *Net* will appear. Expand it by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> to the left of it and you'll see *Skip* appear under it. That means if you don't change anything, `setup.exe` will *not* install `zsync`.

   [image: Velma Dinkley installs zsync in Cygwin while updating her blog in "Siren's Song."]
7. So click once, where it says *Skip*. Now it will install the latest available stable version of `zsync` for Cygwin.

   [image]
8. Click *Next* again to finish the installation. The Cygwin environment, and `zsync`, will be downloaded and installed. (If you're asked to install packages that are required as dependencies, go ahead and do so.)

Once it's installed, open the Cygwin shell. You can run `zsync` from there.

> *References*
>
> - [Installing and Updating Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (official site, very general instructions)
> - [How To Update To The Latest Ubuntu 11.04 ISO Using zsync In Windows](http://digitizor.com/2011/04/19/ubuntu-zsync-windows/) (old and unofficial, but still helpful)
>
> Please note that while you can post on the [Cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/lists.html)
>   for problems with Cygwin (after reading that and the materials it
>   tells you to read), they understandably do *not* support unofficial
>   instructions. `cygwin` has quite good documentation, so like other
>   projects with good centralized documentation (like OpenBSD), they
>   expect that people asking for help will have read the documentation
>   and are working from (or at least very familiar with) it.
>
> (Therefore, if you have trouble with my instructions, *the best place
>   to ask about them is probably here*.)

#### `zsync` on Ubuntu

This doesn't apply in your specific case, but for folks who want to use `zsync` on Ubuntu, just install [zsync [image: Install zsync]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zsync). This can be done in the Software Center or by running this in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install zsync
```

Now you can run it from the Terminal.

Related: [How do I update an ISO with zsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54241/how-do-i-update-an-iso-with-zsync)

#### Using `zsync` to Fix Your Corrupted ISO Images

In the Command Prompt, go to the directory that contains your corrupted ISO file. (You can use `cd` to change directory, same as Ubuntu. Use `dir` to list the contents of a directory.) Make sure the file you have has the same filename as when you got it.

Now run `zsync` in one of these ways, depending on which Ubuntu ISO image it is:

- 12.10, 32-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
  ```
- 12.10, 64-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
  ```
- 12.04.1 LTS, 32-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
  ```
- 12.04.1 LTS, 64-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
  ```
- 12.04 LTS (before the 12.04.1 point release), 32-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
  ```
- 12.04 LTS (before the 12.04.1 point release), 64-bit:

  ```
  zsync http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
  ```

*Once you run one of those commands, `zsync` will automatically patch your ISO up to the correct version, and you're good to go.*

#### Using `zsync` for Other Files

The general syntax is that you run `zsync` followed by a complete URL for the `.zsync` file on the server that has the same name as the file you have a version of and wish to download (except with `.zsync` at the end of course).

In case anyone wants to do this for any other Ubuntu releases (or other ISO files for the same release, like the version optimized for booting properly on Macs or the version for ARM-based mobile devices) here's the rule for where the `.zsync` files are located:

- ISO images containing currently supported installers, including ISO's for the latest point release of LTS releases and all ISO's for currently supported LTS releases, are located in:

  [`http://releases.ubuntu.com/`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)
- ISO images for end-of-life releases (which you shouldn't use anyway) or previous point releases of supported LTS releases are located in:

  [`http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

Just click the link for your version and scroll down to see the full file list (or search the page for `.zsync`). Then copy the URL and paste it in the `zsync` command.

#### Use in "Upgrading"

You can also use `zsync` to "upgrade" one ISO to another. It will probably have to redownload most of the file if you're upgrading from one Ubuntu release to another. But if you're upgrading point releases (like 12.04 LTS to 12.04.1 LTS), it doesn't have to download quite as much. This is an excellent way to get a new point release quickly and efficiently.

Just rename the old file so it has the same name as the new file, then run `zsync` as above.

## BitTorrent

When your Internet connection has a high rate of error, [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bittorrent) is often one of the best ways to download files reliably. Files are divided into many small pieces, and each piece is downloaded and checked to see if it's the real thing. (The individual pieces can be downloaded from different computers, which is what lets BitTorrent avoid putting load on a central server, and achieve speeds often faster than those possible with web-based downloads.)

[Torrents for Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 12.04.1 can be obtained here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

You'll need a BitTorrent "client" to download it. If you don't already have one that you prefer, for Windows I recommend [BitTornado](http://www.bittornado.com/).

After you download, I recommend seeding some if you can, to give back to the community. (With BitTorrent it from people like you.) You don't have to do it right away though--you can go back into your BitTorrent program and seed later. You can even quit it while the download is unfinished, and resume it anytime.

#### Using BitTorrent to Fix the File You Have

<sup>*Warning: This subsection is not as well-researched as the rest of the answer. I have not tested the use of BitTorrent to fix corrupted files recently, or on Windows, or with BitTornado. I expect this would work for you, but I cannot be sure.*</sup>

While BitTorrent is not as commonly used for this purpose as `zsync`, the BitTorrent protocol itself is just as capable of it.

Some BitTorrent programs will do this--others will refuse to, or download the whole file from scratch--unless the file you start with is exactly the same size. (Conveniently, a corrupted download *often* is the same size as the correct file.)

Put the old ISO image in the same folder as the `.torrent` file. Make sure your BitTorrent program downloads the torrent there. It will check to see if your current file is good. When it sees some parts are wrong, it can re-download them.

For some BitTorrent programs, you must import the file as a torrent in progress, or open it for seeding, in order to do this.

Comment: This is a rather epic answer.

Comment: @Nanne Thanks! Btw if you happen to know more details than I provided about using BitTorrent to repair pre-existing files, please edit this to provide better information about that (if you wish).

Comment: Wow... Now this is about 10x the answer I was expecting! Thanks! Will give this a try, and either accept, or update the question with some more details!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ISO Master](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/) if you want to add and remove files to the ISO. It's available for both Windows and Linux.