# How to download Ubuntu over an unreliable connection

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to download the 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10 ISO over an extremely unreliable connection. By unreliable, I mean that every time I finish downloading the ISO and compare the MD5 hashes, I end up with an error about a mismatch.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 to perform the download. Is there a tool that can somehow work around a very unreliable connection?

Comment: How about just [buying it on CD](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976)? If you only have such an unreliable connection, that might be the easier solution, and it's still almost gratis.

Comment: In case you do want to buy it from Canonical as @leftaroundabout suggests, [here's a link for 12.10](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1027).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my case my connection drops a lot and if trying to download the ISO directly I also end with a MD5 problem. What I recommend is downloading the ISO image through a torrent client.

That way, even while downloading, the torrent client checks to make sure it is OK. There is a [good list of torrents to use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients) but if you are in Windows or Mac, I suggest [UTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/). If you are doing this from an Ubuntu installed computer, Ubuntu comes with a default torrent client called [Transmission [image: Install transmission]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/transmission).

You can find the [torrent download file in the ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) just look for the file with the **.torrent** file extension.

Answer (score 12):

Besides [bittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/a/274629/22949), you can also use `zsync` (a free tool) for this.

You'll probably want to know how `zsync` works in order to decide whether or not you want to obtain and use it, so I'll explain how it works first, and then how to obtain it.

### How to Use `zsync` to Download an Ubuntu ISO Image

`zsync` lets you build one file by starting with another. You can start with any file, but to offer any advantage over simply downloading the file you need, the file you start with should be *similar* to the file you want.

`zsync` only works for files whose providers have created a `.zsync` metafile. A `.zsync` file contains checksums for sections of a file, and enables the `zsync` utility to figure out what parts of the file you already have match, and what parts do not. Parts that do not match are downloaded again. (Actually, `zsync` is a bit more sophisticated--it is also able to handle situations where some parts match but are in different places in the file, without having to redownload those matching parts. That particular feature is not frequently helpful in creating a good file from a corrupt download, however.)

Once you have a (corrupted) ISO image downloaded somewhere, open a Terminal or (for Windows) Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) and navigate to its location. In most OSes you can type `cd` with a space at the end and then drag a folder to the command line, and the location of the folder will be pasted. Then you can press enter and it will **C**hange **D**irectory to that location. (`cd` should be lower case--on some systems, like Windows, upper-case will work, but on other systems, like OS X and Ubuntu, it will not.)

Once you're in the folder that has the file--running `ls` or `dir` should show you everything in there, and running `ls *.iso` or `dir *.iso` should show you just files that end in `.iso`, which includes Ubuntu installation images--then run:

```
zsync URL-to-.zsync-file Ubuntu-iso-image-name.iso
```

That will patch up the corrupted file you have (named like `Ubuntu-iso-image-name.iso`--for example, it may be called `ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso`) to be correct. If you run it and no changes are made, that means your file is correct. `zsync` incorporates checksums, so you can be sure you have a complete, correct file if it says you do.

***To learn precisely how to obtain `.zsync` on multiple platforms, and how to run it for each Ubuntu ISO image, read on.***

### Getting the `zsync` Utility

I've written about getting and using `zsync` to fix corrupted ISO images before, in a different context. It was in [a longer answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239868/22949) most of which is not related to this question here. So I've excerpted the parts of it that are related.

> #### Getting `zsync` for Windows
>
> `zsync` traditionally runs on Unix-like system (which doesn't really
>   include Windows). However, recently [a native Windows port of `zsync`
>   has been created](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/zsync-windows/new_dashboard), so you can probably use that.
>
> `zsync` is a command-line program, so in Windows you run it in the
>   Command Prompt. (One way to open the command-prompt is to type
>   `cmd.exe` into the text box in the Start menu and press
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or, in Windows XP and earlier, Start > Run >
>   `cmd.exe`.)
>
> #### Another Way: Getting `zsync` for Cygwin
>
> If you have any problems with the Windows port of `zsync`, you can
>   always use the Cygwin version. Cygwin provides a Unix-like environment
>   for Windows. It does not allow compiled executables to be run (for
>   example, you could not use `zsync` from the Ubuntu package), but uses
>   special versions of programs compiled for it from source. (It is far
>   easier to compile a program written for Unix-like operating systems in
>   Cygwin, than to compile it so it works natively on Windows.)
>
> 1. First, [get Cygwin's installer (`setup.exe`) from here](http://cygwin.com/) (or use [this direct link](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)).
> 2. Run it, click **Next** on the first screen, then select *Install from Internet* and click **Next** again.
> 3. On the next two screens, put Cygwin and the local package directory wherever you like them (defaults are usually good).
> 4. Select your Internet connection type (*Direct Connection* is usually good), and `setup.exe` will download a list of mirrors.
> 5. Pick any mirror, and it will download a list of available packages. You'll probably be warned about how this version is different from the
>      previous one. That's not a problem, unless you've been using a
>      previous version of Cygwin on the same machine.
>
>    [image: Setup Alert message about how how this is the first time you've installed this particular version of Cygwin. If you haven't used Cygwin before, this can be ignored. As it says, "If this is the first time you've installed Cygwin on this system then you can ignore this message."]
> 6. Now you can select what packages to install. There is a text box for searching packages by name. Type `zsync` there (but *do not* press
>      <kbd>Enter</kbd>--if you do, it's like clicking *Next*). An entry for
>      *Net* will appear. Expand it by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> to the left of it and you'll see *Skip* appear under it. That means if you don't
>      change anything, `setup.exe` will *not* install `zsync`.
>
>    [image: Velma Dinkley installs zsync in Cygwin while updating her blog in "Siren's Song."]
> 7. So click once, where it says *Skip*. Now it will install the latest available stable version of `zsync` for Cygwin.
>
>    [image]
> 8. Click *Next* again to finish the installation. The Cygwin environment, and `zsync`, will be downloaded and installed. (If you're
>      asked to install packages that are required as dependencies, go ahead
>      and do so.)
>
> Once it's installed, open the Cygwin shell. You can run `zsync` from
>   there.
>
> > *References*
> >
> > - [Installing and Updating Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (official site, very general instructions)
> > - [How To Update To The Latest Ubuntu 11.04 ISO Using zsync In Windows](http://digitizor.com/2011/04/19/ubuntu-zsync-windows/) (old and unofficial, but still helpful)
> >
> > Please note that while you can post on the [Cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/lists.html)
> >     for problems with Cygwin (after reading that and the materials it
> >     tells you to read), they understandably do *not* support unofficial
> >     instructions. `cygwin` has quite good documentation, so like other
> >     projects with good centralized documentation (like OpenBSD), they
> >     expect that people asking for help will have read the documentation
> >     and are working from (or at least very familiar with) it.
> >
> > (Therefore, if you have trouble with my instructions, *the best place
> >     to ask about them is probably here*.)
>
> #### `zsync` on Ubuntu
>
> This doesn't apply in your specific case, but for folks who want to
>   use `zsync` on Ubuntu, just install [zsync [image: Install zsync]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zsync).
>   This can be done in the Software Center or by running this in a
>   Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install zsync
> ```
>
> Now you can run it from the Terminal.

<sup>***From [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239868/22949) to [How to identify and replace broken files in a corrupted Ubuntu ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239822/how-to-identify-and-replace-broken-files-in-a-corrupted-ubuntu-iso)***</sup>

### Using `.zsync` to Fix the Most Common Ubuntu ISO Files

First, `cd` to the location containing the corrupted `.iso` image, as explained above (in **How to Use `zsync` to Download an Ubuntu ISO Image**).

> Now run `zsync` in one of these ways, depending on which Ubuntu ISO
>   image it is:
>
> - 12.10, 32-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
>   ```
> - 12.10, 64-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
>   ```
> - 12.04.1 LTS, 32-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
>   ```
> - 12.04.1 LTS, 64-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
>   ```
> - 12.04 LTS (before the 12.04.1 point release), 32-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
>   ```
> - 12.04 LTS (before the 12.04.1 point release), 64-bit:
>
>   ```
>   zsync http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
>   ```
>
> *Once you run one of those commands, `zsync` will automatically patch your ISO up to the correct version, and you're good to go.*

<sup>***From [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239868/22949) to [How to identify and replace broken files in a corrupted Ubuntu ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239822/how-to-identify-and-replace-broken-files-in-a-corrupted-ubuntu-iso)***</sup>

### Writing `zsync` Commands for Other (and Future) Ubuntu `.iso` Images

> The general syntax is that you run `zsync` followed by a complete URL
>   for the `.zsync` file on the server that has the same name as the file
>   you have a version of and wish to download (except with `.zsync` at
>   the end of course).
>
> In case anyone wants to do this for any other Ubuntu releases (or
>   other ISO files for the same release, like the version optimized for
>   booting properly on Macs or the version for ARM-based mobile devices)
>   here's the rule for where the `.zsync` files are located:
>
> - ISO images containing currently supported installers, including ISO's for the latest point release of LTS releases and all ISO's for
>     currently supported LTS releases, are located in:
>
>   [`http://releases.ubuntu.com/`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)
> - ISO images for end-of-life releases (which you shouldn't use anyway) or previous point releases of supported LTS releases are located in:
>
>   [`http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)
>
> Just click the link for your version and scroll down to see the full
>   file list (or search the page for `.zsync`). Then copy the URL and
>   paste it in the `zsync` command.

<sup>***From [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239868/22949) to [How to identify and replace broken files in a corrupted Ubuntu ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239822/how-to-identify-and-replace-broken-files-in-a-corrupted-ubuntu-iso)***</sup>

While it is *considerably broader* than this (and I *do not* recommend that they be considered duplicates!), if you're interested you might want to take a look at the question that originally led me to write most of the text here (i.e., the text enclosed in blockquotes):

- [How to identify and replace broken files in a corrupted Ubuntu ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239822/how-to-identify-and-replace-broken-files-in-a-corrupted-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded a lot of Ubuntu .iso images over the years and every time I downloaded an Ubuntu .iso image it maxed out all the available capacity from my internet service provider, except for the single time I tried downloading the Ubuntu .iso file from a torrent mirror site which was a lot slower. Your mileage may vary, so if you don't want to waste your time waiting for the Ubuntu .iso to finish downloading you should try downloading it with both http and torrent, and cancel the download that is slower.

btw I always download all Ubuntu iso images from the [official Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) and I use a download tool that has resume interrupted download functionality like *wget* has using `wget -c file.iso` or [GNU Wget for Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#download), so I don't have to download the same bits twice.

```
-c
--continue
    Continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when
    you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
    wget or by another program.
```

An alternative to wget that works on all platforms (Windows/Mac/Linux) is the popular [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) extension for Firefox. DownloadThemAll will help you select, queue, sort and run your downloads faster. It comes with advanced ways to select what links to download, and will remember your previous decisions so that you can queue more downloads with just one click. DownloadThemAll can also automatically or manually restart interrupted downloads in the same place where they were interrupted so you don't lose the part of the file that you already downloaded.