# Problem installing Ubuntu on Several computers

Tags: system-installation

I am trying desperately to place Ubuntu on four types of machines. SO far I cannot install to even one of them. My three machines are a Mac Desktop running OS x , with a 2.6 Intel core 2 duo processor. An Acer laptop running windows 8 its serial is Acer Aspire 5735-4774, a powerbook g4 17" mac,  and finally I have a asus Tf300 laptop I would like to try Ubuntu in as well.

I have been able to easily fragment disk drives for space for the installation, Im able to get into the boot menu to run usb or off cd  for all the machines. I have used retfit and unetbootin for the mac, and unetbootin for pc.

My biggest problem I believe is finding a non corrupted .iso file from UBUNTU. I have downloaded 12.04 and 13004 several times and last night I even tried the bit torrent way. I have even tried using the feature of Unebootin to do so. NO success so far.

I am trying to get an .iso file to create a live cd (boot disk) so I can try UBUNTU.

Any tips ? Im about to walk away. these downloads take 1 1/2 hour and its so frustrating when they are corrupted.

thank you in advance --david

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please tell us if the `.iso` file (at least the one downloaded with bit torrent) are actually corrupted. For Windows you can try [md5sum](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmd5sum_portable) or similar software. This question is because often the problem with live CDs has to do with the speed at which it was burned. Did you try burning the CD at the lowest speed?

Comment: Please see here on your case of downloading Ubuntu as a corrupted ISO (This is more of an internet problem than an Ubuntu problem): http://askubuntu.com/questions/274628/how-to-download-ubuntu-over-an-unreliable-connection/274629#274629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with UNetbootin. The live USB is a better way of storing data than burning a CD/DVD.

The md5 checksum hash is used for file verification. The [Ubuntu Documentation UbuntuHashes wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) contains all of the md5 Hashes for the different versions of Ubuntu. Let's assume that you downloaded a file called FILE.iso to your Downloads folder on a Mac computer, and you want to find its md5 checksum. To find the md5 checksum of a file called FILE.iso on a Mac, open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
md5 FILE.iso
```

Comment: OK. I believe I can just about close this question up. As it turns out only a few of my files are corrupted and a few of them checked out fine. I recommend using the terminal type md5 space and drag file to get checksum. As it turns out my MAcs disks utility no longer supports md5  SInce then I have installed ubuntu on the windows machine and have tested it on the mac (no wireless support ). I still have tons of questions how to get it installed on my older g4 processor, but right now I am good.  Oh and thank you all very much !