# Wanted Ubuntu, got Mint

Tags: mint

I went to Ubuntu and went to the download page, chose 32 bit, for an older machine, made a CD.  When everything was said and done, I have Linux Mint 16 on the machine....how did that happen?  I'm new to Linux, but I can't find anywhere that it says this is what I was downloading.  Is it because I chose 32 bit?  Is it a screw up in the mirror?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you download it from?  Ubuntu doesn't provide Mint images, is it possible you were on the Mint site instead?

Comment: The correct place to download Ubuntu is http://www.ubuntu.com/download. Is this the site you downloaded it from?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop specifically.  I've looked at the image file and it even says ubuntu, but once the CD is loaded, it's desktop background says Linux Mint 16

Comment: Then it must be magic! :~)

Comment: This is kind of a long shot, but is it possible that this person has Ubuntu installed but their desktop wallpaper is set to one of the Mint ones?  Ie, could there have been any Mint wallpapers included with the Mate or Cinnamon packages or other packages which originate from Mint?

Comment: Could you explain what was your problem? Did you write wrong ISO image(Mint iso file)? Did you check the md5 of your downloaded iso file? PLEASE REPLY

Comment: It was not Ubuntu installed.  The layout and look are completely different.  I proceeded to download the 64 bit version from the same site (ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and got ubuntu this time around.

The ISO image was labelled as ubuntu.  I can not answer more than that right now, because the project was left at the persons home.  I'm not sure how it happened, the 32 bit came out as 'mint' and the 64 bit came out ubuntu.  I will check the md5 (hopefully they didn't throw the disc out, as I told them it wasn't what they had wanted) when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mirror is [automatically selected](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Metalink) when you download Ubuntu at http://www.ubuntu.com/download or http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. That's usually a very good way to get Ubuntu, but some problems, potentially including a wrong file on a mirror, can be solved by downloading directly from http://releases.ubuntu.com. I strongly suspect that will fix this for you, *if the problem is really that your ISO image is for Mint.*

You can also [download with bittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/a/274629/22949).

To figure out what happened, I recommend very carefully checking through all the steps you carried out while burning the CD, in case you accidentally selected the wrong ISO image. Some CD/DVD burning software has confusing interfaces. (This is of course less likely to be the cause, if you have not ever previously downloaded a Mint image.)

<sup>If you'd written the ISO to a USB stick instead of burning it to a disc, I'd suggest making sure you didn't accidentally select the wrong option in the program you used to do that. For example, UNetbootin has an option to specify what OS to write to the USB stick. However, I don't know of any CD/DVD burning programs with similar functionality (and thus am mentioning this primarily for the benefit of others who may find this question while searching for help with a related problem).</sup>

If you wish to investigate this further, you can check that your ISO image is really the Ubuntu ISO you want it to be--and that it has not been corrupted--by [calculating the md5sum of the ISO image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and [checking it against the appropriate ISO image's MD5 hash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).