# Downloading Ubuntu 20.04 on my Win 7 laptop

Tags: 20.04

I am downloading Ubuntu 20.04 on my Win 7 laptop, and it is taking a LONG time (it sez 5 hours). Is this OK? I am worried about leaving my laptop connected to the internet for so long. I always like to get in and get out QUICKLY.

Comment: Which file are you downloading - Windows Subsystem for Linux or standalone Ubuntu 20.04 iso?

Comment: Standalone Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download Ubuntu over an unreliable connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274628/how-to-download-ubuntu-over-an-unreliable-connection)

Comment: To be more correct, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Canonical.

Comment: What is your connection speed?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very slow internet connection.  You might try using a bit torrent software, such as "Transmission" and/or connecting to a coffeeshop wifi which should be better than what it sounds like you have.

Answer (score 0):

You internet connection seems to be slow. If not, try using different mirrors or torrent. But it's fine to wait.