# Not able to install 14.04 from DVD

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation

I have downloaded iso image of Ubuntu 14.04 from the official website. After that I burned it on a DVD, when I boot my computer with the DVD inserted in the drive I see [the following messages](http://s27.postimg.org/pai2h03w3/IMG_20140831_125426.jpg) on a black screen:

[image]

I do not know how to deal with them.

Comment: Did you check the .iso file's md5sum, and verify the burned DVD on the machine on which you're attempting to install? Step 1 of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/22949) to [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/22949) summarizes and links to instructions for how to do those things. If you've done that and the iso image and DVD both check out as good (md5 matches exactly and no files had errors in the verification), please [edit] your question to explain about that. Otherwise a new iso download or new burn may fix it.

Comment: I did a checksum and the one provided on the Ubuntu website does not match with the one I have on the iso. What should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the .iso image turned out wrong when you [tested it](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/22949), you have a bad .iso file. It's highly likely (though not certain) that this is the cause of the problem.

- You should make sure you're comparing against the correct hash, though. [The hashes here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) are missing for some of the newer iso files. In particular, it doesn't currently have the md5 hashes for the 14.04***.1*** images, which is what you likely downloaded if you downloaded 14.04 recently.
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/MD5SUMS includes the MD5 hashes of the 14.04.1 images.

You should download the iso again, md5 test the new one, and assuming that one is good, burn a new DVD from it. If the .iso file has a different md5sum from what it's supposed to have, that means it got corrupted, most likely during download. (Or it's possible the download didn't finish all the way.)

Corruption in file downloads is the exception rather than the rule, so most likely this second download will work. You should md5 test it too, though.

But if the md5sum of the new iso is wrong too, then provided you're comparing it to the correct official md5sum, that suggests a problem with the quality of the Internet connection used to download it. You could then use [bittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/a/274629) or [zsync](https://askubuntu.com/a/239868) to download it more reliably.